# Missing cars in GTA Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I put two brand new cars that I just bought in my garage, and because it said that the garage was full, I had to remove these two cars. They were a fully upgraded Sultan RS and a Voodoo Custom, both costing a total of 5.8 million. They have both gone missing and obviously I am quite upset, can anyone please help me track them back?